# How could I choose one particular file to load with loadStrings

Tags: processing

The title is explicit enough, I want to let the user choose the text file he want to open.
I do not know if there is an explorer or an input field already implemented on processing.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [selectInput](http://processing.org/reference/selectInput_.html). From the Processing reference:

> Opens a platform-specific file chooser dialog to select a file for input. After the selection is made, the selected File will be passed to the 'callback' function. If the dialog is closed or canceled, null will be sent to the function, so that the program is not waiting for additional input. The callback is necessary because of how threading works.

I've modified the example sketch they provide in the reference to include loading the file with the `loadStrings` method.

```
String[] txtFile;

void setup() {
  selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected");
}

void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
    String filepath = selection.getAbsolutePath();
    println("User selected " + filepath);
    // load file here
    txtFile = loadStrings(filepath);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Implemented method, but you could could make a buffer and monitor key presses like so:

```
String[] File;
String keybuffer = "";
Char TriggerKey = Something;

void setup(){
  //do whatever here
}

void draw(){
  //Optional, to show the current buffer
  background(255);
  text(keybuffer,100,100);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode >= 'a' && keyCode <= 'z'){
    keybuffer = keybuffer + key;
  }
  if(key == TriggerKey){
    File = loadStrings(keybuffer + ".txt");
  }
}
```

when triggerkey is pressed, it loads the file